# Get Google Review specific review single url

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I've been searching on the web to find a solution, but I find nothing, so I try here !

I get Google Reviews of a place from Google My Business API (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list?hl=fr). It's working well, but I was looking to add one more thing to my reviews datas : it's the link to see the specific advice.

I see that some online widgets tools purpose the link to the advice on Google Maps, like here https://elfsight.com/blog/2022/09/working-with-google-maps-reviews-api/#demo when you click on "Posted on Google", like this for exemple : https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/109534324184565131216/place/ChIJAQBwK_1YwokRZXToEz7Wgs4 but I have no idea how they get this link. Is it from a Google API ? If someone has an idea of how I can generate this kind of URL. I have this part of the URL "/place/ChIJAQBwK_1YwokRZXToEz7Wgs4", but I don't knwo how to get the review ID in that URL (109534324184565131216).

I also see on another tool here https://www.reviewsmaker.com/widget/ that they get another kind of URL, like this : https://www.google.com/maps/reviews/data=!4m8!14m7!1m6!2m5!1sChZDSUhNMG9nS0VJQ0FnSUNSaDRQd0lREAE!2m1!1s0x0:0xe888e88f1ea3a80d!3m1!1s2@1:CIHM0ogKEICAgICRh4PwIQ%7CCgsI5N3XoQYQ4O7jaA%7C?hl=en-US, but it's the same, I really don't know how they get this URL.

I guess there is a way to get single review URL, but it's not possible with only the Google My Business API, the only thing we have it's an ID like this : AbFvOqlTjBYv4Ztx_dT-eGdXFJunLkfRaF6pXT__Z8SSI5gyhBMBH0hZZDUhuGf90L8bNTMz1Sq_

Thank you if anyone can help me about it !

I was looking on Google APIS, but can't find any clue of how the tools get the URL.

I see that we can get reviews from place API but it only get 5 reviews, and I don't see any ID like there is in this url for exemple (https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/109534324184565131216/place/ChIJAQBwK_1YwokRZXToEz7Wgs4) in return.

Answer (score 0):

The Google My Business API does provide a way to fetch reviews for a location, but it doesn't directly give the URL for each individual review. However, maybe there are ways you can try to generate the link to a specific review or at least to the reviews section of a business, **even if the link isn't directly provided in the API response**.

Maybe you can generate a link to the reviews section of a business on Google Maps by using the following format:

> https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=place_id:<PLACE_ID>

replacing <PLACE_ID> with the placeId of the business. This will lead users to the business's page on Google Maps where they can view all the reviews. Remember that it is a **Link to the General Reviews Section**, and not the single review.